# Jquery trigger reset not clearing Validation Errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am resetting the form using the below code.

```
$("#Create").trigger("reset");
```

This is clearing all the values except the validation error message.

I am showing validation error message as below.

```
  @if (ViewData.ModelState.Keys.Any(k => ViewData.ModelState[k].Errors.Any()))
   {
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
         @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Errors: ")
     </div>
    }
```

How can I clear this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just remove those elements

```
$('.alert').remove()
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do reset it clears input fields but you have div filed where errors are generated so you need to clean that.

you can try

```
$("form").data('validator').resetForm();
```

or just

```
  $('.validation-summary-valid').removeClass('validation-summary-errors');
```